# program to ask the user to enter the text file then replace a word with a word in same length

Tags: c, file

i know how to creat a text file and open it but i dont know how to search a word and replace it with a same length word here is my code can you help me please im a kind of beginner
here is my code can you help me adjust it

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <ctype.h>
        #define S_(n) #n
        #define S(n) S_(n)
        #define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 64
        int main()
        {
          char text;
          FILE *newfile;
          newfile = fopen("c:\\program.txt","w");

          if(newfile == NULL)
            {
           printf("Error! Can open the file ");
             return 0;
              }
            printf("Enter your text: \n");
           while ((text=getchar())!=EOF){ fputc(text,newfile);}
             `enter code here` fclose(newfile);
  newfile=fopen("c:\\program.txt","r");
  newfile=fopen("c:\\program.txt","r");
  while ((text = fgetc(newfile))!=EOF)
  printf("%c",text);
  fclose(newfile);

  printf("\n %c",text);

char searchWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1], replaceWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
    //"word" means space delimiter.
    printf("Enter search word\n");
    scanf("%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", searchWord);
    printf("Enter replace word\n");
    scanf("%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", replaceWord);

    long pos = ftell(newfile);//file position at first
    char sentence[1024];
    size_t replace(char *sentence, const char *sword, const char *rword);
    size_t count = 0;

    while(fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, newfile)){
        size_t r_count = replace(sentence, searchWord, replaceWord);
        if(r_count != 0){
            fseek(newfile, pos, SEEK_SET);//back the file position to the position before reading
            fputs(sentence, newfile);
            fflush(newfile);
            count += r_count;
        }
        pos = ftell(newfile);//save file position
    }
    fclose(newfile);
    if(count)
        printf("\nReplaced %zu times.\n", count);
    else
        printf("\nReplacement was not done.\n");
}

size_t replace(char *sentence, const char *sword, const char *rword){
    char *p =sentence;
    size_t sword_len = strlen(sword);
    size_t rword_len = strlen(rword);
    if(sword_len != rword_len){
        fprintf(stderr, "The length of the word is different.(in %s)\n", __func__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//just return 0; ?
    }

    size_t rep_count = 0;
    while(p = strstr(p, sword)){
        if((p == sentence || isspace((unsigned char)p[-1])) && //top of sentence or space precedes word
           (!p[sword_len] || isspace((unsigned char)p[sword_len]))){//end of sentence or space is after the word
           //Word is not part of another word
           memcpy(p, rword, rword_len);
           ++rep_count;
        }
        p += sword_len;
    }
    return rep_count;
}
```

Comment: It seems uncertain whether you want to enter a single character `char text` or a string `printf("Enter text: ");` or an integer `scanf("%d",&text);`.

Comment: i want to enter a string or long text

Comment: 1) Do you want to write to the same file again? 2) What is the replacement word?

Comment: BTW: **Never** do `scanf("%s", ....` The user can cause buffer overflow and make your program fail. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @Bimkl You are using `newfile` without opening the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Stringification
#define S_(n) #n
#define S(n) S_(n)

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 64

int main(void){
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];

    printf("Enter text file name\n");
    if(fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin)==NULL){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = 0;//chomp newline

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+");//r+ : Reading and Writing, The file must exist.
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("fopen:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char searchWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1], replaceWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
    //"word" means space delimiter.
    printf("Enter search word\n");
    scanf("%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", searchWord);
    printf("Enter replace word\n");
    scanf("%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", replaceWord);

    long pos = ftell(fp);//file position at first
    char sentence[1024];
    size_t replace(char *sentence, const char *sword, const char *rword);
    size_t count = 0;

    while(fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, fp)){
        size_t r_count = replace(sentence, searchWord, replaceWord);
        if(r_count != 0){
            fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);//back the file position to the position before reading
            fputs(sentence, fp);
            fflush(fp);
            count += r_count;
        }
        pos = ftell(fp);//save file position
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if(count)
        printf("\nReplaced %zu times.\n", count);
    else
        printf("\nReplacement was not done.\n");
}

size_t replace(char *sentence, const char *sword, const char *rword){
    char *p =sentence;
    size_t sword_len = strlen(sword);
    size_t rword_len = strlen(rword);
    if(sword_len != rword_len){
        fprintf(stderr, "The length of the word is different.(in %s)\n", __func__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//just return 0; ?
    }

    size_t rep_count = 0;
    while(p = strstr(p, sword)){
        if((p == sentence || isspace((unsigned char)p[-1])) && //top of sentence or space precedes word
           (!p[sword_len] || isspace((unsigned char)p[sword_len]))){//end of sentence or space is after the word
           //Word is not part of another word
           memcpy(p, rword, rword_len);
           ++rep_count;
        }
        p += sword_len;
    }
    return rep_count;
}
```

Comment: its helpful but its still not working well when it searches the word and the replacing always fail

Comment: @Bimkl In what case will it fail? It seems to work well for me.

Comment: replacing the word